# Remove only part of "Description" from multiple AD accounts?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to bulk update approximately 1000 users (contained in a CSV) and remove only a portion of the description from their AD profile, without deleting the whole description. For example, I need to remove "Call security before re-enabling this account" from the full description that also includes the users Job information.

Something along the lines of - Description: [*Call security before re-enabling this account.* Human Resource Analyst]

Is there a quick and easy way to do this?

EDIT: 
My apologies, in my haste forgot the code I currently have. Very much learning on the fly here.

```
Import-Modudule ActiveDirectory
Import-CSV -Path "csvlocation.csv" | ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.'User-Name' -Description }
```

That "-Description" part is where I am getting stuck. I know I need to supply two strings, one to find, one to replace. However I don't know what the proper parameter or commandlet (again learning on the fly, apologize for terminology) is in this situation.

FINAL SOLUTION:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Avar = 'Call security before re-enabling this account.'
$Bvar = ' '
Import-Csv -Path "C:\users..." | ForEach-Object{
     $user = Get-ADUser $_.'User-Name' -Properties Description
     Set-ADUser $user -Description $user.Description.Replace($Avar, $Bvar).Trim()
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: @Theo Thank you for the notice. I've updated to the best of my ability.

Comment: @boxdog sorry I didn't show my work! let me know if what I added was sufficient or not. Still learning the community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume your CSV file does not include the current description. That means you first have to retrieve the description, then set it back. Something like this:

```
Import-CSV -Path "csvlocation.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser $_.'User-Name' -Properties Description
    Set-ADUser $user -Description $user.Description.Replace("Call security before re-enabling this account.", "").Trim()
}
```

*Update:* Technically speaking, you can't replace only part of the description. In other words, you cannot tell Active Directory "please replace *this* with *this* in this attribute". You can only tell Active Directory "set this attribute to *this*". (the exception is multi-value attributes, where you can add and remove values)

So you need to do this in multiple steps:

1. Read the current description.
2. Create a new string where you replaced what you want to replace.
3. Set the description to the string you created in step 2.

That's exactly what my example does, although I combined steps 2 and 3 into one line (you could even put the whole thing in one line if you tried).

I can break the code down into more lines so you can see better what's going on. Let's imagine that someone's description says this:

> Call security before re-enabling this account. Human Resource Analyst

You want to remove "Call security before re-enabling this account." (Sorry, I included the "Human Resource Analyst" part earlier, I edited that - I think you want to keep that, right?) But let's look at what happens:

```
$user = Get-ADUser $_.'User-Name' -Properties Description

$currentDescription = $user.Description
#$currentDescription equals "Call security before re-enabling this account. Human Resource Analyst"

$newDescription = $currentDescription.Replace("Call security before re-enabling this account.", "").Trim()
#newDescription = "Human Resource Analyst"

Set-ADUser $user -Description $newDescription
#The description is now "Human Resource Analyst"
```

I also added `.Trim()` so you don't end up with leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Ah! significantly closer to what I need. And your assumption is correct. The only issue is I'm only trying to replace part of the Description, not the whole thing. For example:
Currently=Call security before re-enabling this account. Human Resource Analyst
Remove=Call security before re-enabling this account.
Result=Human Resource Analyst

Comment: I updated my answer. Maybe I misunderstood what you said in your comment, but there's more information there anyway. You can modify the values you pass to `.Replace()` as you need.

Comment: Not sure why but it was taking forever to update in AD and I think my impatience was getting the best of me. I've changed your code slightly to reflect exactly what we are trying to accomplish. However - thank you for all of your help!!